# What does it take to become a moderator on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, moderation

What does it take to become a moderator on this website! I mean how it feels to be a moderator, like given the features of an admin on a Linux system!

Comment: There's an [election](http://stackoverflow.com/election) going on right now. You can nominate yourself if you meet the requirements.

Comment: @3ventic I don't think that's the question user2841280 is trying to ask.

Comment: @RyanCarlson Me neither, it was a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @3ventic I was talking about the edit you just made.

Comment: @3ventic the header may be confusing pls look at the question!

Comment: I accidentally a moderator.

Comment: I don't know why down vote, i was jus ask in difference in normal users and moderator tools is that wrong!

Comment: The one mutually agreed-upon use for downvotes on questions is lack of research, and your question appears to be easily answered by reading the election page.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. There's obviously a language barrier here, but do try to edit your question to clarify your question. Are you asking about what personality traits a Moderator should have? Are you asking about the tools that a Moderator has that normal users don't? Are you asking about how a Moderator feels being a moderator?

Comment: I wish I was a moderator :\

Comment: For your edit: 1) is easily answered from the election page, following links therein. 2) *cannot* be answered, really. Except that every single moderator answers it.

Comment: 1) Don't edit your question to completely change what it's asking.  If you have an entirely new question, ask a new question.  Why would you roll back an edit fixing the grammar/wording of your post to make it easier to read?

Comment: Are you perhaps confusing a "moderator" with a "system administrator"? Those are not the same.

Answer (score 13):

It feels like standing on top of a tall hill, watching all the peasants below you toil at their work, barking corrective commands at them as they fail to meet your standards...

Or, it feels like being some random guy, tossed into a room of unruly teens and being told you are in charge...

Or, it feels like being a janitor at a huge sporting venue, trying to keep it spotless *while the event is still ongoing*...

Or, it feels like being an evil, Nazi, Unicorn Overlord...

Or... I'm not actually sure what you are asking.

Comment: No Herding cats?

Comment: @mikeTheLiar No, that's what the community team does.

Answer (score 8):

I imagine it feels quite a lot like being a school janitor. You get to deal with the worst of the worst content and misbehaving users. You get to have your integrity, intelligence, impartiality, and technical acumen called into question.

It also requires a bit of OCD and, at least as far as Stack Overflow specifically is concerned, a Sisyphean philosophy, because there will always be more flags to handle than you can ever process.

Comment: A perfect description.